# Plotting an integral as a function of a variable

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I want to plot

```
F[x_] := 
  Integrate[
    (1/
      (1 + 
        (64*x^2*Sin[y]^2*Sin[(1/2)*Sqrt[(-8 + x)^2 - x^2*Sin[y]^2]]^2)/
          (((-8 + x)^2 - x^2*Sin[y]^2)*(x^2 - x^2*Sin[y]^2))))*Cos[y], 
    {y, -(Pi/2), Pi/2}]
```

over the interval `{x, 0, 30}`.

I am trying:

```
Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 30}]
```

but without success. How can I do it?

Comment: Wouldn't a numerical approach make more sense for plotting?: `Clear[F]; F[x_?NumericQ]:= NIntegrate[...]`

Comment: I am very sorry, Thank you very much for your appreciable help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael E2 advises in his comment, defining `F` as a numeric function works well when you want to see a plot.

```
F[x_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
    (1/
      (1 + 
        (64*x^2*Sin[y]^2*Sin[(1/2)*Sqrt[(-8 + x)^2 - x^2*Sin[y]^2]]^2)/
          (((-8 + x)^2 - x^2*Sin[y]^2)*(x^2 - x^2*Sin[y]^2))))*Cos[y], 
    {y, -(Pi/2), Pi/2}]

Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 30}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: That's what i want. Thank you